# Pandas: re-shape/ re-pivot a data frame after groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, reshape

I am applying the `quantile` function on the `duration` column of my data frame:

```
a=df.groupby('version')[['duration']].quantile([.25, .5, .75])
a

                   duration
version     
4229        0.25    1451.00
            0.50    1451.00
            0.75    1451.00
6065        0.25     213.75
            0.50     426.50
            0.75     639.25
9209        0.25     386.50
            0.50     861.00
            0.75     866.00
2304        0.25     664.50
            0.50     669.00
            0.75     736.50
6389        0.25       1.00
            0.50     797.00
            0.75     832.00
```

I am wondering how do I re-shape/re-pivot the above data frame, so the new data frame (yes, it has to be a data frame format) could look like:

```
version   duration_Q1    duration_Q2    duration_Q3

4429      1451.00        1451.00        1451.00
6065      213.75         426.50         639.25
9209      386.50         861.00         866.00
2304      664.50         669.00         736.50
6389      1.00           797.00         832.00
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us some data so we can replicate `a`, e.g. `a.to_dict()` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), followed by some renaming operations

```
a = pd.DataFrame('duration': {(2304L, 0.25): 1565.6861959516361,
  (2304L, 0.5): 446.4769649280514,
  (2304L, 0.75): 701.8254115357969,
  (4229L, 0.25): 1868.982390749203,
  (4229L, 0.5): 242.36201172579996,
  (4229L, 0.75): 789.482292226787,
  (6065L, 0.25): 1421.9585894685038,
  (6065L, 0.5): 357.04491735326343,
  (6065L, 0.75): 169.78973203074895,
  (6389L, 0.25): 1789.1550141153925,
  (6389L, 0.5): 516.9365429825862,
  (6389L, 0.75): 1830.6493228794639,
  (9209L, 0.25): 1129.853279993191,
  (9209L, 0.5): 1759.1258334115485,
  (9209L, 0.75): 1499.0498929925702}}
)

pvt = a.unstack()
pvt.columns = pvt.columns.droplevel(0)
pvt.rename(columns={0.25:'duration_Q1',0.5:'duration_Q2',0.75:'duration_Q3'},inplace=True)
```

---

```
        duration_Q1  duration_Q2  duration_Q3
version                                       
2304     1565.686196   446.476965   701.825412
4229     1868.982391   242.362012   789.482292
6065     1421.958589   357.044917   169.789732
6389     1789.155014   516.936543  1830.649323
9209     1129.853280  1759.125833  1499.049893
```